# Using db.PropertyReference in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have two models:

```
class Person(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty()
  role = db.StringProperty(default = "", choices = ["Engineering", "Marketing",  "Care",     "Sales"])

class Item(db.Model):
  user_name = db.ReferenceProperty(Person)
  computer_type = db.StringProperty(default = "", choices = ['Dell Latitude E6500', 'Dell Latitude E5510', 'Dell Latitude E5500' ])
  hostname = db.StringProperty()
  serial  = db.StringProperty()
```

I would like to store them using the Name from the Person modle as the user_name in the Item Model, and display them on a webpage.

My get looks like this:

```
class ItemPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    query_comp = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Item ORDER BY user_name")
    template_values = {
            'query_comp': query_comp
            }
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'table.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

And the table.html looks like this:

```
{% for item in query_comp %}
<tr style='white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis;'>
    <td>{{ item.fname }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.computer_type }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.hostname }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.serial }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

The error I get is AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'has_key'

I am pretty sure my issue is I am not referencing the name object from the Person model correctly, I am currently returning just the key object to the Item model, and that is where I am breaking. I have tried going over the docs, but they have nothing pertaining to using a Gql query as far as I have researched. I think I have to pass into the query a `Item.person.name` object, but I am a bit lost. Looking for some guidance, thanks.

Comment: You should include a stack trace as none of your code shown calls 'has_key' method.

Comment: Try Removing "ORDER BY user_name". I think this part of query is producing the error